# HTML Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Doesn't Dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I am learning how to use Flask (A python module to help develop HTML pages) and I've also included bootstrap to create my navigation bar, but for some reason the drop down menu for the navigation doesn't drop down.

Here's the actual drop down menu code:

```
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Navigation</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <!-- Dropdown menu -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">

                <!-- Menu Title -->
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Animals
                </a>

                <!-- Dropdown -->
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

                    <!-- Dinosaur Link -->
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/dinosaur_homepage">Dinosaurs</a>

                    <!-- Link Divider -->
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                    <!-- Birds Link -->
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/birds_homepage">Birds</a>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And here's the entire source code (excluding the python file): https://pastebin.com/VhrxkbYi

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have missed js and css file

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Navigation</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <!-- Dropdown menu -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">

                <!-- Menu Title -->
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Animals
                </a>

                <!-- Dropdown -->
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

                    <!-- Dinosaur Link -->
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/dinosaur_homepage">Dinosaurs</a>

                    <!-- Link Divider -->
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                    <!-- Birds Link -->
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/birds_homepage">Birds</a>
                </div>

            </li>         
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Will they not load if they’re in the head tag?

Comment: @SeanCantwell you're using it within head tag?

Comment: No, I just placed them there for organization purposes. (I also had them at the end of the body tag believing they had to be within the body, but even then it seemed not to work so I moved the script tags and css link to the head.

Comment: are you using bootstrap 4 or 3?

Comment: The downloaded file for bootstrap is named bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2-dist.zip.

Comment: go through this link https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/